# django 1.8 application migrated to new server rises strange exception

Tags: django, typeerror

We had this Django 1.8 application working in the server we setup 6 months ago (Fedora 24 64-Bit). Yesterday we setup a new server with same packages and now we suddenly get this error:

> Django Version:   1.8 Exception Type:     TypeError Exception Value:
>
> _new_pool() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request_context'
>
> Exception Location:
>     /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py in
>   connection_from_pool_key, line 262 Python Executable:     /usr/bin/python
>   Python Version:   2.7.11

Seemingly offending code:

```
# Make a fresh ConnectionPool of the desired type
259             scheme = request_context['scheme']
260             host = request_context['host']
261             port = request_context['port']
262             pool = self._new_pool(scheme, host, port,   request_context=request_context)
263             self.pools[pool_key] = pool
```

May the Django 1.8 files have changed in repository so this doesn't work anymore? seems very strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of urrlib3 are you using? Try upgrading it because request_context was added in [this commit 9 months ago](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/commit/7c14966fc134146223650a8393e17e91a358ba6d).

Answer (score 0):

D. Nibon, you are my hero. That was the problem. seems that python-urllib3 package was not installed in this machine. Solved!

Comment: Great! Please accept my answer and let us both move on and create great django applications. :)

Comment: I don't see option in StackOverflow to mark answer as accepted, but your reply was exactly what I needed to head in the right direction. Thank you very much!

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".